# I am trying to build a Hybrid Application using Oracle jet Framework.I am trying to Build I'm not getting any Error.But apk not generating

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

Like this I'm Getting Error. APK not generating. If I created new App then its working but previous app is not working. **Build is Not generating**
sorry for the bad english

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of cordova-android platform are you using?

The problem you stated is an issue with cordova-android@7.0.0 or later when you build Oracle JET applications. There is no fix for it yet in the latest update. It is better to downgrade the cordova-android version to a more stable version, preferably to 6.2.3 or 6.4.

You can replace the current version by using the command:

```
cordova platform remove android
```

You can re-add the platform of a specific version using the command:

```
cordova platform add android@6.2.3
```

**Note**: type these commands from the hybrid directory of your project using ojet-cli.